# Restrict user input to positive integers in wpf datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid in which i have quantity field which is off type integer. Now i want to restrict my user to enter only positive integers. I dont want a solution of handling inputs on datagrid key events. Any suggestions?

And Here is the convertor i am using

```
public class ValueConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        { return value; }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (!OnlyPositiveIntergerAllowed(value.ToString()))
            {
                string s = Regex.Replace(value.ToString(), @"[^0-9]+", string.Empty);

                if(s=="")
                return 0;
                else
                    return s;

            }
           if (value is string && (string)value == "")
            {
                return 0;
            }

            return value;

        }
        private static bool OnlyPositiveIntergerAllowed(string text)
        {
            var regex = new Regex("[^0-9]+"); //regex that matches disallowed text
            return !regex.IsMatch(text);
        }
}
```

Note: Its working fine (i.e. if 123dasd. it converts on lost focus 123), but i allows user to input (dasd.).

Comment: Please can you post the XAML for your DataGrid so I can see how it is set up?

Comment: here is xaml

<DataGridTextColumn Header="Amount" Binding="{Binding Amount,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource decimalConverter}}" />

Comment: Try setting the type of Amount to uint and don't use any converter on the binding

Comment: I'm unclear, you want to allow the input of "dasd", but if they put in a numeric value, it has to be a positive integer?

Comment: Did you consider doing this in the Set?  Are you binding to a Public Property?

Comment: Sorry for being late. I want only positive integers. But user should not be able to enter anything other than integers.

Answer (score 1):

The solution you seek is called validation.

A search for **WPF validation** will provide plenty of links, here is one that looks pretty good: http://wpftutorial.net/DataValidation.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DataGridTemplateColumn` and `IntegerUpDown` from the [Extended WPF Toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/) for this situation.

Example:

```
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Amount">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <toolkit:IntegerUpDown 
                                    Minimum="0"
                                    Value="{Binding Amount}"
                            />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

You can also use [DecimalUpDown](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DecimalUpDown).

Comment: Amount can be in thousands so integerupdown is not best option

Comment: @user1825783 your question is "Restrict user input to positive integers..." so IntegerUpDown  is good option. If you look at the documentation Extended WPF Toollkit you can find there DecimalUpDown control. Usage of this control is similary to usage of IntegerUpDown control.